# Websocket in limited Lua?

Tags: lua, network-programming

I'm looking to make a project involving websockets in pure lua, but the environment I have available is limited. There is no io or require. All I can do is HTTP `get` and `post`. Using only this, is it possible to make something like a websocket? I'm not very sure myself if it's possible.

Using PHP and HTTP get, I can read and write files.

edit: no external libraries or c libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use external PHP libraries?
PHP does have some websocket libraries:
http://socketo.me/

It wouldn't be easy, but you could use HTTP GET/POST requests for this.
The right request creates a socket, while other requests control it.
Using a "websocket session" you can do it, but are you sure you need it?
If you're limited to only regular HTTP GETs and POSTs, it won't help much.